# Google App Engine (GAE) basic scaling backend instance serves one request and undeploys

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed an application (frontend and backend) in App Engine. First of all, I am using the free tier and I chose the default F1 for the frontend and B2 for the backend. I don't exactly understand the difference between B and F instances but based on their names, I chose them for backend and frontend respectively.

My backend is a Flask application that reads some data from Firestore on `@app.before_first_request` and "pre-caches" it for all future requests. This takes about 20-30 seconds before the first request is served so I really don't want the backend instance to become undeployed all the time.

Right now, my backend successfully serves one request (that I am making from the browser) and then immediately gets undeployed (basically I see no active instances in App Engine dashboard after the request is served). This means that every request once again has the same long delay upon server start that I don't want. I am not sure why this is happening because I've set idle timeout to 5 minutes. I know it is not a problem with my Flask application because it does not crash after a request on a local machine and I've done its memory profiling which is in bounds of B2 limits. This is my app.yaml for the backend:

```
runtime: python38
service: api
env_variables:
  PORT: 8080
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 5m
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information and behavior that you are exposing, please allow me to explain to you that both Scaling models are behaving as they are designed to do so.

“Automatic Scaling: It creates instances based on request rate, response latencies, and other application metrics. You can specify thresholds for each of these metrics, and a minimum number instances to keep running always.

Basic Scaling: Basic scaling creates instances only when your application receives requests. Each instance will be shut down when the application becomes idle. Basic scaling is ideal for work that is intermittent or driven by user activity.”

Use the following URL’s documentation as reference for those models and more of them [How Instances are Managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed).

> > Information added on 10/12/2021:

Hi,

I think the correct term is “shutdown” instead of “undeployed” [Disabling your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_your_application). Looking at [Instance States](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_states) "an instance of a manual or basic scaled service can be either running or stopped. All instances of the same service and version share the same state." then looking at [Scaling types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) "Basic scaling creates instances when your application receives requests. Each instance will be shut down when the application becomes idle. Basic scaling is ideal for work that is intermittent or driven by user activity." and the table's Startup and shutdown row for basic scaling "Instances are created on demand to handle requests and automatically shut down when idle, based on the idle_timeout configuration parameter. An instance that is manually stopped has 30 seconds to finish handling requests before it is forcibly terminated." and [Scaling down](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_down) "You can specify a minimum number of idle instances. Setting an appropriate number of idle instances for your application based on request volume allows your application to serve every request with little latency".

Could you please verify:

- that the instance was not manually halted?
- that instance is becoming idle?
- that there are no background threads?
- if functionality is the same when setting the [max_instances to 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194552)
- that there are no logs showcasing an instance shutdown
- that they are reaching the version with the updated the idle_timeout set

Comment: Looks like OP understands that but his instances are shut down before idle_timeout is reached.

Comment: Yes as @Asdfg said, I read through the documentation multiple times. I set the idle timeout for a reason, so I'm not sure why it is shut down immediately after the first request is served.

Comment: I just updated my answer adding useful information for you and some steps.

Comment: I think the issue was I didn't measure memory consumption properly. I was using more than what I had allocated. I shifted from GAE to Cloud Run and the logs helped me figure that out.